# SSMS UpdatedDTTM not updating automatically?

Tags: sql, datetime, set, ssms

I'm new to the world of SQL/SSMS (I'm taking a foundational course on udemy and have picked up a lot but am still a beginner). I've been creating some demo tables for practice and need a bit of clarity on the following: I've created an employee table (see pic below), the table has a CreatedDTTM column and an UpdatedDTTM column... the Created is working fine, but no matter how many times I update a certain cell (e.g. change an employee's LastName), the corresponding UpdatedDTTM still shows as NULL. I was assuming that it would update automatically each time I change an entry, or have I got the wrong end of the stick?

[image]

Comment: did you commit after the update statements?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I don't usually use the commit command when entering values/updating them, I just do update/set/where and give my new values, highlight the paragraph and click Execute. The entries do update in my table, but the date and time field doesn't change to show the update.